# How come PXUIField attribute disables text edit boxes on a processing page in 2019 R1?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to setup a processing page that will update a SOShipment document lines with new data entered on the PXFilteredProcessing page. When declaring a PXString (virtual field), if I add the PXUIfield attribute, the field becomes read only.

Here is the DAC declaration showing the actual problem. The page I use is a simple PXFilteredProcessing page with a completely custom page that was made in Visual Studio.

```cs
#region StockRow

public abstract class stockRow : IBqlField { }
[PXString()]         
[PXUIField(Enabled = true)]
public virtual String StockRow { get; set; }

#endregion

#region StockFlag

public abstract class stockFlag : IBqlField { }
[PXString]        
public virtual String StockFlag { get; set; }

#endregion
```

The page has the fields defined as follow :

```xml
<px:PXTextEdit ID="edStockRow" runat="server" 
DataField="StockRow" Enabled ="true" >
</px:PXTextEdit>
<px:PXTextEdit ID="edStockFlag" runat="server" 
DataField="StockFlag" Enabled ="true">
</px:PXTextEdit>
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="StockRow" Width="200px" >
</px:PXGridColumn>
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="StockFlag" Width="200px">
</px:PXGridColumn>
```

Should the PXUIField really make the field become read only or is there something I am not getting?

PS: I know I can re-enable the field on the RowSelected even, I'm mostly looking for an explanation as to why this is happening.

Comment: as the answer provides this is how a processing graph functions by default. All fields should also have a PXUIField. You can enable fields as you mentioned in row selected to update some values before processing. Nothing wrong with that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I add the PXUIfield attribute, the field becomes read only

Are you sure that this is the operation making the field read-only?

Typically all processing screen detail fields are disabled except the Selected column. I believe this is a behavior introduced by the use of `PXProcessing` type data view. Going against that behavior will likely not yield the desired result.

If the screen needs detail fields to be editable (except Selected column) I would advise not to create a processing screen. Using a `PXSelect` data view instead will provide correct behavior for the editable fields.

Comment: Well this is the trigger that made the field non-editable. If I only declare the PXString, the PXProcessing screen still allows me to edit the StockFlag field. Adding PXUIField attributes disables this behavior. It is easily tested and reproducible. It might be a bug in the end but that is what I noticed.

Comment: Without PXUIField attribute, is it really a StockFlag field? Is there a field label in the grid column?  Does it load and save values properly? As Brendan mentioned, for UI use 'All fields should also have a PXUIField'. Without it the grid cell could be editable but it could also not be bound to the target field.

Comment: Yes it does load and yes you can edit it and processing of the field works fine so far.. Of course it doesn't display a formatted label since we didn't declare any, but it does show the field name. 
Screenshot of the fields in the grid:[fieldname](https://imgur.com/uRJkWc5)
Screenshot of the value at runtime: [value](https://imgur.com/RJRXT4C)

I understand it's required, I'm just questioning what exactly the system is doing in the background

Comment: The processing view might only inspect fields which have PXUIField attribute. It's not expected that field on UI is missing that element so the result is more or less undefined behavior. I would still advise not to omit that attribute.